# TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.5.1)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

When trying to deploy my smart contract, I get this error message:

> TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed",
> code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.5.1)
>
> at main
> (C:\Users...\simple-storage\backend\scripts\deploy.js:16:26)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   code: > 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
> argument: 'key',   value: 'deployed' }

I'm using hardhat for deploying with this deploy.js code:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const simpleStorageContract = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    "SimpleStorage"
  );

  const deployedContract = await simpleStorageContract.deploy("Hello World!");

  await deployedContract.deployed(); // error is here

  console.log("SimpleStorage Contract Address:", deployedContract.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the changes in hardhat-tools 3.0.0.
Make the following changes **deploy** => **deployContract**,
**deployed** => **waitForDeployment**

So your main function would look like -

```
async function main() {
  const deployedContract = await ethers.deployContract("SimpleStorage",["Hello World"]);

  await deployedContract.waitForDeployment();

  console.log("SimpleStorage Contract Address:", await deployedContract.getAddress());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. SimpleStorage is the name of the contract. Where do I include "Hello world", which is the string input of the constructor?

Comment: Inputs to constructor can be provided as the second parameter of deployContract in the form of an array, I have edited the answer to include this.

Comment: I started using hardhat 2.16.0 and hardhat tools 3, so the last line of code to get address should be changed to: `await deployedContract.target`

Answer (score 1):

```
const deployedContract = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Hello World!");
await deployedContract.waitForDeployment(); 
console.log("SimpleStorage Contract Address:", deployedContract.target);
```

Replace your code with above one, It will work without any errors.

Comment: SimpleStorage is the name of the contract. Where do I include that? Hello world is just the string input of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was able to solve it by installing the earlier version of hardhat.
(I didn't try Alwin's answer/code yet with the new version3.0.0 of hardhat; their answer might work instead of downgrading the version, like I'm suggesting.)

instead of: `npm install --save-dev hardhat`

do: `npm install --save-dev --save-exact hardhat@2.14.0`

---

instead of: `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`

do: `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox2`

Answer (score 0):

I have the following script in my deploy.js:
const hre = require("hardhat");

```
const main = async () => {
  const transactionsFactory = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Transactions");

  await transactionsFactory.waitForDeployment();

  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsFactory.getAddress());
  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsFactory.address);
  console.log("Transactions address: ", transactionsFactory.target);
  console.log("Hello World!");
};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

`runMain();`

When I run npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli I see Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully in the terminal, but no other messages which I expected from the console.log statement. Now I am not sure if the contract was deployed successfully or not. Why is  console.log not showing in the terminal? I am using VS Code Solidity extention by Juan Blanco,    "hardhat": "^2.15.0" and "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0".