# I am trying to deploy this contract but facing this error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

// Returns the ether balance of a given address.
async function getBalance(address) {
  const balanceBigInt = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
  return hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceBigInt);
}

// Logs the Ether balances for a list of addresses.
async function printBalances(addresses) {
  let index = 0;
  for (const address of addresses) {
    console.log(`Addresses ${index} balance: `, await getBalance(address));
    index++;
  }
}

// Logs the memos stored on-chain from coffee purchases.
async function printMemos(memos) {
  for (const memo of memos) {
    const timestamp = memo.timestamp;
    const tipper = memo.name;
    const tipperAddress = memo.from;
    const message = memo.message;
    console.log(`At ${timestamp}, ${tipper} (${tipperAddress}) said: "${message}"`);
  }
}
console.log("2");
async function main() {
  // Get the example accounts we'll be working with.
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("3");
  const BuyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('BuyMeACoffee');
  const buyMeACoffee = await BuyMeACoffee.deploy();
  console.log("4");
  // Deploy the contract.
  await buyMeACoffee.deployed();
  console.log("6");
  console.log("BuyMeACoffee deployed to:", buyMeACoffee.address);
  console.log("5");
  // Check balances before the coffee purchase.
  const addresses = [owner.address, tipper.address, buyMeACoffee.address];
  console.log("== start ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Buy the owner a few coffees.
  const tip = { value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1") };
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Rahul", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Suprit", "You're a good coder", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper3).buyCoffee("Prasad", "You're a good coder", tip);

  // Check balances after the coffee purchase.
  console.log("== bought coffee ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Withdraw.
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(owner).withdrawTips();

  // Check balances after withdrawal.
  console.log("== withdrawTips ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Check out the memos.
  console.log("== memos ==");
  const memos = await buyMeACoffee.getMemos();
  printMemos(memos);

}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

but facing this error ->

```
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.3)
    at makeError (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:670:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:706:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:542:23)
    at buildWrappedMethod (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:334:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:859:22)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:757:39)
    at main (C:\Users\rohan\OneDrive\Documents\CODES\BuyMeACoffee\scripts\deploy.js:43:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'deployed'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/151233/typeerror-no-matching-function-argument-key-value-deployed-code-invalid

Comment: Yeah, I tried using that but i am facing problem on getting address. It is showing the same error but this time when I am trying to get address at console.log("--", buyMeACoffee.address)

Comment: I also encountered the same problem, did you solve it?